# MoviePy OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe | BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python, moviepy, oserror

macOS Ventura 13.5

I'm trying to split an audio mp4 file into few chunks to add one of them to a video clip.
Here is the code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
audio = AudioFileClip('/Users/User1/Desktop/video_creating/my_music.mp4')
clip = audio.subclip(1, 25)
clip.write_audiofile('samples/sample_1.mp4')
```

But its shows me an error message reporting:

```
OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file sample_1.mp4:

b"[aost#0:0 @ 0x131e39240] Invalid encoder type 'libx264'\n"
```

What am i doing wrong?

Is there any other ways to edit audio/video files in Python?

I tried to uninstall ffmpeg then install it again.
Tried to do brew install lightgbm. But still nothing seems to be work.

Comment: How you have installed ffmpeg ? If you have installed it via binary, make sure it is available in environment variable PATH

Comment: Yes, ffmpeg is installed.
Interpreter path is in the .venv folder.
Installed by "pip install ffmpeg"

Comment: Also make sure extension of output file is mp3 `clip.write_audiofile("sample_1.mp3")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and I believe the file type `mp4` is incorrect and the folder `samples` does not exist which causes the error

You have to pass a `.mp3` file to the `AudioFileClip()` function and make sure you have a folder called `samples`

However you can use [`moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools.ffmpeg_extract_audio`](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/ffmpeg.html#moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools.ffmpeg_extract_audio) to extract sound from an `.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed x264 and ffmpeg packages, you can install them with following command.

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg x264
```

After installing above packages, please make sure when you're calling `write_audiofile()` extension of output file is `mp3` or `wav` because this library uses encoder based on extension we provide. In your case you were getting error because you were providing mp4 extension.

**Code snippet:**

```
from moviepy.editor import *
audio = AudioFileClip('sample-5s.mp4')
clip = audio.subclip(1, 4)
clip.write_audiofile("output.mp3")
```

**Output:**

```
MoviePy - Writing audio in output.mp3
MoviePy - Done.
```

Comment: Thank you. This code works too. Its possible to give mp4 audio file and get mp3 just by file output extension.